# How to convert values in a numpy matrix based on a condition?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to convert all the values that are zero to one, as referenced in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310347/numpy-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-this-message-may-app). Using the indexing method has no effect on the matrix though.

[image]

How would I change all the 0's in my matrix to -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your boolean indexing is failing because `new_train_data` is currently a matrix of *strings* (`dtype='|S3'`), not floating point numbers!

You can cast the matrix to `dtype=np.float64` to convert it to floats, then use boolean indexing to assign a value of `-1` to all elements that are equal to `0.0`:

```
new_training_data = new_training_data.astype(np.float64)
new_training_data[new_training_data == 0] = -1
```