# Ordering of strings and tuples in pandas index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

With the following DataFrame:

```
baz = pd.DataFrame({("a", "b"): [1, 2, 3], "g": [11, 12, 13]})
```

if I try to select columns from it like this:

```
baz[[("a", "b"), "g"]]
```

everything is fine. If, however, I access it like this:

```
baz[["g", ("a", "b")]]
```

I get an error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

Is this a bug, or something I'm doing wrong? I'm using pandas 0.22.0, the same happens with 0.20.1

Edit: This is not the same as [Numpy ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. This message may appear without the existing of a sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310347/numpy-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-this-message-may-app) since I'm not explicitly setting anything *per se*. (Although it may of course relate to the same underlying bug; I have no idea.)

Comment: This *appears* to be a bug. Or, at the very least, inconsistent treatment. One way that works fine is to use `frozenset({'a', 'b'})` instead of `('a', 'b')`. This may or may not suit for your use case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. This message may appear without the existing of a sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310347/numpy-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-this-message-may-app)

Comment: This is a numpy thing.  There is commentary at the dupe about a workaround that I tested successfully.

Comment: I understand the problem is due to `numpy` (and that's where the "fix" lies). But I thought the whole point of `pandas` overhead is to deal with all the edge cases / provide flexibility versus strict `numpy` requirements.

Comment: Sure you might call it a bug but why are we using a tuple as a column name here?