# Converting OpenCV SURF features to float32 arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, surf

I extract the features with the `compute()` function and add them to a list. I then try to convert all the features to `float32` using NumPy so that they can be used with OpenCV for classification. The error I am getting is:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Not really sure what I can do about this. I am following a book and doing the same steps except they use HOS to extract the features. I am extracting the features and getting back matrices of inconsistent sizes and am not sure how I can make them all equal. Related code (which might have minor syntax errors cause I truncated it from the original code):

```
    def get_SURF_feature_vector(area_of_interest, surf):
            # Detect the key points in the image
            key_points = surf.detect(area_of_interest);
            # Create array of zeros with the same shape and type as a given array
            image_key_points = np.zeros_like(area_of_interest);
            # Draw key points on the image
            image_key_points = cv2.drawKeypoints(area_of_interest, key_points, image_key_points, flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
            # Create feature discriptors
            key_points, feature_descriptors = surf.compute(area_of_interest, key_points);
            # Plot Image and descriptors
            # plt.imshow(image_key_points);
            # Return computed feature description matrix
            return feature_descriptors;

    for x in range(0, len(data)):
            feature_list.append(get_SURF_feature_vector(area_of_interest[x], surf));
list_of_features = np.array(list_of_features, dtype = np.float32);
```

Comment: Is the formatting of the function wrong? I see you referencing `area_of_interest` outside the function.

Comment: Yeah but that's not what I was getting at. Imagine area of interest was just an arbitrary image loaded into the function. Focus lies at the data structure created by surf.compute and how I can convert it to an array of float32.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. This message may appear without the existing of a sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310347/numpy-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-this-message-may-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error isn't specific to OpenCV at all, just numpy.

Your list `feature_list` contains different length arrays. You can't make a 2d array out of arrays of different sizes.

For e.g. you can reproduce the error really simply:

```
>>> np.array([[1], [2, 3]], dtype=np.float32)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

---

I'm assuming what you're expecting from the operation is to input `[1], [1, 2]` and be returned `np.array([1, 2, 3])`, i.e., concatenation (actually this is not what OP wants, see the comments under this post). You can use the `np.hstack()` or `np.vstack()` for those operations, just depending on the shape of your input. You can use `np.concatenate()` too with the `axis` argument but the stacking operations are more explicit for 2D/3D arrays.

```
>>> a = np.array([1], dtype=np.float32)
>>> b = np.array([2, 3, 4], dtype=np.float32)
>>> np.hstack([a, b])
array([1., 2., 3., 4.], dtype=float32)
```

Descriptors are listed vertically though, so they should be stacked vertically, not horizontally as above. Thus you can simply do:

```
list_of_features = np.vstack(list_of_features)
```

You don't need to specify `dtype=np.float32` as the descriptors are `np.float32` by default (also, `vstack` doesn't have a `dtype` argument so you'd have to convert it after the stacking operation).

---

If you instead want an 3D array, then you need the same number of features across all images so that it's an evenly filled 3D array. You could just fill up your feature vectors with placeholder values, like 0s or `np.nan` so that they're all the same length, and then you can group them together as you did originally.

```
>>> des1 = np.random.rand(500, 64).astype(np.float32)
>>> des2 = np.random.rand(200, 64).astype(np.float32)
>>> des3 = np.random.rand(400, 64).astype(np.float32)
>>> feature_descriptors = [des1, des2, des3]
```

So here each image's feature descriptors have a different number of features. You can find the largest one:

```
>>> max_des_length = max([len(d) for d in feature_descriptors])
>>> max_des_length
500
```

You can use [`np.pad()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) to pad each feature array with however many more values it needs to be the same size as your maximum size descriptor set.

Now this is a little unnecessary to do it all in one line, but whatever.

```
>>> feature_descriptors = [np.pad(d, ((0, (max_des_length - len(d))), (0, 0)), 'constant', constant_values=np.nan) for d in feature_descriptors]
```

The annoying argument here `((0, (max_des_length - len(d))), (0, 0))` is just saying to pad with 0 elements on the top, `max_des_length - len(des)` elements on the bottom, 0 on the left, 0 on the right.

As you can see here, I'm adding `np.nan` values to the arrays. If you left out the `constant_values` argument it defaults to `0`. Lastly all you have to do is cast as a numpy array:

```
>>> feature_descriptors = np.array(feature_descriptors)
>>> feature_descriptors.shape
(3, 500, 64)
```

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your response. Could the problem be that I don't extract an equal amount of features every time? When I do print(feature_descriptors.shape), it gives me a matrix of [x, 64], with varying amounts for x depending on how many features were extracted from the sample. If I understand correctly, would making x be the same value every time solve my problem?

Comment: Exactly, but simply `np.vstack()` them together would also solve your problem---this is what you probably want to achieve, anyways (just an array of shape `(total_n_features, 64)`).

Comment: Hmmm, I don't seem to get the error anymore, but I am also not getting the feature array that I want - it should be [nr_of_images, nr_of_features, 64] I believe, not just [nr_of_features, 64]. Is there anything that you might know that could help me? Otherwise i'll just mark it as correct, since it did get around the error...

Comment: Oh! In that case then yes---what you proposed in the past comment is what you want do likely do. The images won't have the same number of features, but you can fill the rest up with dummy vals (like `np.nan` or something) so that you get an even 3d array. I'll update with that.

Comment: @Borzi added an example of how you could instead achieve the shape you want.

Comment: I was being silly - I need to use a Bag of Words function or something like that to get it working properly. Thanks for the help!