# using tensorflow:feed_dict,ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
for i in range(iter_time):  
    for step in range(len(batch_index)-1):
        _,loss_=sess.run([train_op,loss], feed_dict={X:train_x[batch_index[step]:batch_index[step+1]], Y:train_y[batch_index[step]:batch_index[step+1]]})  
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print('iter:',i,'loss:',loss_)
```

where `train_x[batch_index[step]:batch_index[step+1]]` is a list with shape `(80, 15, 44)`. I have tried to convert `train_x` to `np.array` but it still not work.

Comment: Please format your code so that it is readable.

Comment: I have format my code just now.

Comment: This is a numpy error. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310347/numpy-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-this-message-may-app/39114489